# lift error, method not found

Tags: scala, lift, code-snippets

I am calling this snippet

```
package org.palantir.snippet
import net.liftweb._
import util._
import Helpers._
import scala.xml._

object Kitchens
{
  def render(html: NodeSeq) : NodeSeq = <p>test</p>
}
```

With this xml

```
      <lift:Kitchens>
      </lift:Kitchens>
```

And getting this error:
Error processing snippet: kitchens 
Reason: Method Not Found
What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This occurs because the HTML5 parser Lift uses converts all tag and attribute names to lowercase. It is recommended to use either: `class="lift:Snippet"` or `data-lift="Snippet"` to avoid that. This was not an issue with the older XHTML parser as that was case sensitive, so you will find some older documentation that invokes snippets as a tag.

You can find more information [here](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/HtmlProperties_XHTML_and_HTML5).